# Nested bat/cmd syntax error stops all parent flow, any way to solve?

Tags: batch-file

Look at these two BAT files please.

nest0.bat

```
@echo off

echo nest0 start.

call nest1.bat

echo nest0 done.
```

nest1.bat

```
@echo off

if 1 = 1 (
    echo In nest1
)

echo nest1 done.
```

Run nest0.bat and we will see this output:

```
nest0 start.
= was unexpected at this time.
```

This is terrible. Syntax error in `nest1.bat` causes remaining statements in `nest0.bat` to be totally neglected, and the whole batch flow stops immediately.

I hope `echo nest0 done` can be executed no matter `nest1.bat` succeeds or fails. Any way to achieve that result?

If `nest0.bat` can continue execution, I can use `if ERRORLEVEL 1 (...)` technique to check for `nest0.bat`'s execution result. It will be a very decent workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch itself doesn't survive a fatal error.
But you can start the second batch file in a seperate cmd.exe process.
Replace `call nest1.bat` with `cmd.exe /c nest1.bat`, that's all

nest0.bat

```
@echo off
echo nest0 start.
cmd /c nest1.bat
echo nest1 done.
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo nest1 was successfully
) else (
    echo nest1 failed
)
```